# php54 common conflicting with php53 common when installing php-xml for XMLReader

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, centos, redhat

Specifically, on Amazon Linux, Error: php54-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.23-1.33.amzn1.x86_64 when issuing

sudo yum install php-xml

I uninstalled php54-common and installed php-xml fine, but it installs php53-common which is not compatible then with php 5.4.

It seems like php-xml is not supported on Amazon Linux if I want to continue with PHP 5.4

--skip-conflicts does not resolve the problem.

I wonder if anyone has suggestions or agree with my theory.

Answer (score 0):

I found a package php54-xml that works. I thought I'd checked for it but guess not.